# want to add register and loginout options to menu wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This is my header file where i wants to add loginout and register links in header menu.....

```
           <nav class="navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation" id="site-navigation">
            <a class="screen-reader-text skip-link" href="#content"><?php          _e( 'Skip to content', 'zerif-lite' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right responsive-nav main-nav-list', 'fallback_cb'     => 'zerif_wp_page_menu')); ?>
        <?php wp_register(); ?>
        <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add login/logout to menu Woocommerce Wordpress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179863/add-login-logout-to-menu-woocommerce-wordpress)

Comment: You should be adding Login/Logout from your Functions.php file.  Check this one. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156217/add-logout-link-to-navigation-menu

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be ok, but you should be sure that your admin settings are well configured:

From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register):

> The "Register" link is not offered if the Administration > Settings > General > **Membership: Anyone can register** box is not checked.

Hope it helps!